# Clean shutdown Spring Integration and Spring Boot when using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration and Spring Boot for some development on my location machine based on the Spring Guides. I am using Gradle to build and run the application. The following code is used to bootstrap Spring and I can terminate the application by pressing the enter key.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);
        System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    } 
}
```

This works fine but when I introduce a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) into the integration flow, the application never terminates. I have to use ^C to kill the application. The code I am using is as follows.

```
    ...
    channel(MessageChannels.executor(myTaskExecutor()))
    ... 

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(10);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        pool.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(1);
        pool.initialize();
        return pool;
    }
```

I have:

1. Tried to shutdown the executor (using the shutdown()) method) before and after the context is closed.
2. Tried the above code also within the onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) method.
3. Temporarily commenting the code which is run in the thread to make sure that is not holding on to the thread in any way.

Is there any anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.close()` will shutdown any executor beans (by calling the `destroy()` method), so it is likely you have a thread "stuck" somewhere.

Take a Thread dump (`jstack`) to see what the executor thread is doing.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I ran a `jstack <pid>` and it gave me the following [output](https://pastebin.com/F9dJrdcQ).

Comment: I think it's because you're calling `initialize()` - you shouldn't do that because Spring will do that for you; it looks like if it's called twice you get two pools.

Comment: I initially thought I didn't need the `initialize()` method but if I remove it, I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException:ThreadPoolTaskExecutor not initialized` exception. Not sure if there's something wrong with my Bean definition above.

Comment: Then there's something very weird going on. Can you post the complete `@Configuration` class?

Comment: Aaha.... school boy error on my part. I had called the executor like this `channel(MessageChannels.executor(myTaskExecutor()))` which was calling the method directly. I have now removed the `initialise()`, autowired the task executor bean and referenced it like this  `channel(MessageChannels.executor(myTaskExecutor))` and it works correctly now. Thank you for bearing with me and your help :)